# Как CountDownTimer поставить на паузу

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Есть таймер обратного отсчета, который проигрывает движение объекта, при котором объект появляется в центре экрана в виде точки, приближается и покидает экран. Все это сделано с помощью придания объекту нужных LayoutParams в нужное время. Все движение объекта занимает 9 сек, его layoutParams обновляются каждые 100 миллисек. Нужное время обозначено в методе onTick таймера:

```
 timer = new CountDownTimer(9000,100) {

 @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

 if (millisUntilFinished<8800){
//скорость движения объекта увеличивается
}
  if (millisUntilFinished<6000){
//скорость движения объекта еще увеличивается
}
}
```

Все работает отлично, но есть проблема с остановкой.
Допустим, пользователь хочет остановить движение объекта, коснувшись экрана:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(firstClick){

                timer.cancel();
            }else{
                timer.start();
            }
            firstClick=!firstClick;
```

В этом случае счетчик не становится на паузу, как хотелось бы, а просто завершает выполнение задачи. И, когда пользователь вновь нажимает на экран, таймер запускается с первоначально установленными параметрами, т.е. опять на 9000 сек.

А хотелось бы, чтобы он продолжил выполнение задачи, т.е. начал с тех миллисек, на которых закончил. Т.е. если пользователь остановил счетчик, когда до его финиша оставалось 5000 сек, то счетчик должен запустить движение объекта со скоростью, которая заложена в

```
 if (millisUntilFinished<6000){
//скорость движения объекта еще увеличивается
}
```

и "протикать" не 9 сек, а (9000-5000=4000) 4 сек.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего надо сделать что-то типа этого

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 paused = !paused; //boolean с более понятным названием
```

И в самом `onTick()` просто проверять

```
@Override
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       if(!paused){         
           if (millisUntilFinished < 8800){
              //скорость движения объекта увеличивается
             }
           if (millisUntilFinished < 6000){
              //скорость движения объекта еще увеличивается
           } 
       }
```

В этом случае, если `!paused`, то логика тика будет скипаться

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, есть еще одна проблема: а где тогда создавать в таком случае экземпляр CountDownTimer? Если его создавать в oncreate, то проблема не решается, а вот если в ontouch, тогда да, тогда объект проходит весь путь (от точки в середине экрана до вылета за пределы экрана, но... получается, что после того, как отработал таймер и объект исчез, создается новый таймер, таким образом, движение продолжается, что видно по "заднему плану" (картинка, которая увеличивается по мере движения объекта) Как можно предотвратить создание нового таймера ?